# Joint probability integration limits

Tags: probability, integration

My teacher asked us to determine the value of $k$ to make the following function a probability density function:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}k, &0 \leq x \leq2,0\leq y \leq1, 2y\leq x\\0, &\text{ elsewhere }\end{cases}$$

I understand I need to double integrate and fix $k$ so that the result of the integration is $1$, but the limits confuse me.

Here's what I have:
$\int_0^2\int_0^1 k \ dy\  dx=2k$

This yields $2k=1$, so $k=0.5$.

I can't help but think I'm missing something! I'm not using the additional constraint that $2y \leq x $ and I'm not sure how to use it.

Any help or hints would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2y \leq x \implies y \leq \frac{x}{2}$$

$$1 = \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{x}{2}} k dy dx = \int_{0}^{2}\frac{kx}{2}dx = \frac{kx^2}{4}\bigg\rvert_{0}^{2} = k$$

Comment: I´ve recognized that I was too late.

Comment: Thank you. I understand better.